# overwrite parent .resizable property for grandchild elements, maybe using css?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have a main parent div that is .resizable(). One of it's child divs, say bottomChild has alot of other child div's, which resize as well. However, they have text and this text does not resize and so overlaps with other sibling div contents. What i want is for them to not resize, but for a scrollbar to appear so that the user can scroll through the bottomChild and see the content. I have a GridView in another child Div, say topChild, and this happens for the GridView automatically. I want to simulate this for bottomChild as well. Does anyone know how?

Heres a running sample - http://jsfiddle.net/xgCDy/33/
Try and resize the black parent div and see the content overlap.

Comment: can you show me part of your code?

Comment: @EmRa228 i have added a jsfiddle for your reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved your problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/WGknf/embedded/result/

just remove some extra code :D

http://jsfiddle.net/WGknf/

dont use relative(%) height. when you use draggable div!!!!

Comment: Thank-you @EmRa228! That was indeed the issue!